# How to highlight some cells in a dataframe through different condition for each column? Is also possible highlighting some number in a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, highlight

I'm working with Python and I have a serious (I really can't understand how I can solve it) problem for highlighting some cells in my dataframe. 
I show you my doubt:
I have 2 matrix and the shape is the same in both of them.
One of this matrix is made just by 0/1 and the other matrix has decimal numbers. 
I would highlight the element in the matrix made by decimal numbers but with a condition on the matrix made by 0/1. So for example: if in the matrix made by 0/1 I have a cell with 1 THEN I would highlight the same cell in the other matrix (ex: in my matrix you can see that in the first cell I have 1 so I would highlight the first cell of the other matrix (0.000034)). 
I really don't know how I can write this.

I also thought to divide my dataframe in singular column and working with one by one and then put all column together, maybe could be easier? but...I didn't find how I can highlight some element in a Series because notebook sayes to me that Series hasn't attribute "apply" (when I write "Series.style.applyect). Is it possible?

Thank you for your help!

Result= pd.DataFrame({'First':[1,1,1,1,1, ...], 'Second': [1,1,1,0,1, ...], 'Third': [0,0,0,0,0, ...], 'Fourth':[1,1,1,1,0, ...]})

Values= pd.DataFrame({'One':[0.000034, 0.000043, 0.000023, 0.000055, 0.000034, ...], 'Two': [0.000011, 0.000087, 0.000045, 0.000065, 0.000024, ...], 'Three': [0.000054, 0.000026, 0.000043, 0.000022, 0.000024 ...], 'Four':[0.000011, 0.000025, 0.000053, 0.000036, 0.000026, ...]})

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,1], [3,2,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))
df_mask = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,1], [0,0,0], [0,1,1]], columns=list("ABC"))


def highlight_mask(df, df_mask, color='yellow'):
    '''
    highlight the cells with df_mask.
    '''
    df_mask.replace(1, 'background-color: {}'.format(color), inplace=True)
    df_mask.replace(0, '', inplace=True)
    return df_mask


df.style.apply(highlight_mask, df_mask=df_mask, color='red', axis = None)
```